# entire function with no zeros. Then $f$ must be of the form $f(z)=\exp(g(z))$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function with no zeros. Then $f$ must be of the form $f(z)=\exp(g(z))$ where $g$ entire.

Is it true or not? How to prove?

Comment: It's a standard result, available in introductory complex analysis textbooks. Note it can be rephrased: $\log f$ is entire.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I don't believe that reference is a valid duplicate, if only for the scope and OP's apparent perspective (one can't expect freshmen to navigate the accepted answer, although the second should probably be okay).

Comment: To OP: try looking at a primitive of $\frac{g^\prime}{g}$.